# The intersection of all normal ultrafilters on a measurable cardinal

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals, ultrafilters

Suppose $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal. Let $W$ be the intersection of all normal ultrafilters on $\kappa$.
I am interested in a precise characterization of the filter $W$.

One sure way to conclude that a set $A$ is in all normal measures, is to find a regressive function $f$ on $\kappa\setminus A$ such that $\forall\beta<\kappa:\space\space |f^{-1}(\beta)| <\kappa$.
So we can define $W'$ to be the set of all such subsets $A$, i.e. subsets of $\kappa$ such that there exist such a regressive function $f$.
The main question is as follow:

**Question 1:** Is it consistent that $W=W'?$ Is it consistent that $W \neq W'?$

It is also interesting to know the consistency strengths.
The following is an equivalent form of a privet case where there is only one normal measure.

**Question 2:** Suppose that there is only one normal measure on $\kappa$. Consider the statement: For every $A\subset\kappa$ there is a regressive function $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ s.t for all ordinals $\beta,\gamma<\kappa$, $|f^{-1}(\beta)\cap A|<\kappa$ or $|f^{-1}(\gamma)\cap (\kappa\setminus A)|<\kappa$. Is this statement and it's negation consistent?

I would be very happy if you can give me some advice or references for those questions. Thank you very much for every help.

**Note:** By regressive function I mean a function which is regressive on all of its domain but a number $<\kappa$ of ordinals.

Comment: Concerning question 1:  The set $W'$ is usually called the club filter, and the complements of sets in $W'$ are called nonstationary sets.

Comment: I do not understand question 2.If $A$ is unbounded then you can take $f$ constant on $A$ .

Comment: I have edited it so it's ok now

Comment: Vaguely related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336511/stationary-sets-and-kappa-complete-normal-ultrafilters

Answer (score 2):

The answer to Question 1 is no. Your filter $W$ contains the set of inaccessible cardinals below $\kappa$, but the club filter $W'$ does not.

Comment: why not? we can take $f$ of a non inaccessible ordinal to be its cardinality if it's not a cardinal, it's processor if it is not a limit cardinal, and it's cofinality if it's singular.

Comment: why does that preclude the existence of some $\beta$ such that $|f^{-1}(\beta)|=\kappa$? In fact there exists one since the non-inaccessible ordinals is stationary.

Comment: @Otto You're right. For example, below any measurable (or even just inaccessible) $\kappa$, there are $\kappa$ singular cardinals $\lambda$ of cofinality $\omega$. So all $\kappa$ of these would have $f(\lambda)=\omega$ for the proposed $f$.